# heroku 503ing Asynch API calls on my React App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, http-status-code-503

I am so close to finishing up a project - the coding of it was simple enough, but deployment has been a nightmare. I've got it mostly deployed, but now the app is timing out on API calls, even though they work fine on my localhost server.

and here is the error I'm getting:

```
at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/api/retrieve/skills" host=derek-smith-portfolio.herokuapp.com request_id=d1f5c23e-4fd1-4348-a1e7-dffbd72bb47b fwd="47.24.173.21" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

Any clue what might be causing this? I can't seem to figure it out, it works just fine locally, and the API calls i've seen on postman are all under 500ms. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed, I had initially kept my mongo_uri variable in quotes in heroku's environmental vars. removing the quotes fixed the issue.